# Does an Android Bitmap from BitmapFactory decode() contain transparent information?

Tags: java, android, bitmap, transparency, animated-gif

I have ported a Java implementation of AnimateGIFWriter to Android [here](https://github.com/dragon66/android-gif-animated-writer). It works fine except I don't get the transparency. I tried to pass an `Options` to the decode() method like this:

```
Options opts = new Options();
opts.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fin, null, opts);
```

After reading the input image into a Bitmap, I will grab the data as an int array through `Bitmap.getPixels()` and auto-detect the transparency from the alpha value. But this doesn't work - the resulting animated GIF is not transparent (The input images are all transparent and my code is supposed to keep them through auto-transparency detect. This works for desktop application).

I am not quite familiar with Android related stuff. My question is given the above configuration, will `BitmapFactory.decode()` keep the transparency information of the input image?

**Update:** I found out for images support full alpha transparency like PNG images, it does keep the transparency information. But for single color transparency images like GIF, it seems not. This needs further confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

> My question is given the above configuration, will BitmapFactory.decode() keep the transparency information of the input image?

Yes, transparency/alpha should be loaded into that bitmap.

To verify this, you could try fetching the value of a single pixel -- maybe (0,0) -- and printing it to the log.

I don't have the time (or desire) to get into your full 1600 lines of code, but I would be suspicious of this part in the `writeFrame` method:

```
 if(frame.getTransparencyFlag() == GIFFrame.TRANSPARENCY_INDEX_SET && frame.getTransparentColor() != -1) {
```

Comment: Thanks, Snild. The suspicious line is all part of the auto transparency detection. It is unlikely that would produce any problem.

Comment: For full alpha transparency like PNG images, I found the loaded Bitmap does keep the transparency. But for single color transparency like GIF images, it seems not.